# How can I access variable from callback function in other nested functions?

Tags: javascript, callback

Help me understand something. I have nested functions and I need to get data from lowest (deepest) to highest (first function - func1). As suggested by @spectras I do try use promises instead of callbacks to no avail.

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if (array[i] == '3'){
        function tfunc1(){
            function tfunc2(){
                function tfunc4(){
                    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
                        setTimeout(function(){ // lets suppose that there is some async work here
                            var tsomeData = 'TsomeData';
                            resolve(tsomeData);
                            reject(console.log('tfunc4 ERROR'));
                        }, 2000);
                        console.log('TsomeData callback will be executed after 2 sec');
                    });
                }
            }
            tfunc2();
            function tfunc3(){}
            tfunc3();
        };
        tfunc1();
    }

    if (array[i] == '6'){
        function afunc1(){
            function afunc2(){
                function afunc4(){
                    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
                        setTimeout(function(){ // lets suppose that there is some async work here
                            var asomeData = 'AsomeData';
                            resolve(asomeData);
                            reject(console.log('afunc4 ERROR'));
                        }, 2000);
                        console.log('AsomeData callback will be executed after 2 sec');
                    });
                }
                afunc4();
            }
            afunc2();
            function afunc3(){}
            afunc3();
        };
        tfunc1();
    }

    // I need to work with tsomeData here - how to pass it here?
    // I need to work with asomeData here - how to pass it here?

    // some tsomeData + asomeData manimupulation:

    function after(){
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            setTimeout(function(){ // lets suppose that there is some async work here
                var newData = tsomeData + asomeData;
                resolve(console.log(newData));
                reject(console.log('after ERROR'));
            }, 2000);
            console.log('AsomeData callback will be executed after 2 sec');
        });
    }

    tfunc4().then(function(tsomeData)
    {
        return afunc4(tsomeData);
    }).then(function()
    {
            return after();
    }).catch(function()
    {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

how to do that in node?

EDIT: code update. And some more details cause of post is mostly code..

Comment: You cannot. Your outer function will have finished running long before your callback is called. Have a look at Promises

Comment: Spectras, thanks. Could you give me some promise example to look at that solve this problem?

Comment: I suggest you check something like https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises

Comment: jsfiddle.net/loleczek/19bvo4vh/35 - I can't get this to work with promises - how to run promise so it can get all scattered functions?